# Requiring client-dynamodb produces syntax error (related to uuid) on node version 18.13.0

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb, uuid

The following line in my express app

```
const ddbClient = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
```

works fine on node v14.15.0, but after upgrading to v18.13.0 the following error is produced:

```
/mnt/e/CODING/nzgk_series/2/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3541
    ClientRequestToken: input.ClientRequestToken ?? (0, uuid_1.v4)(),
                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/e/CODING/nzgk_series/2/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/commands/BatchExecuteStatementCommand.js:8:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

I used nvm to jump between the two versions, added and removed this line and confirmed that it was causing the issue.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.245.0",
    "@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb": "^3.245.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you got any solution for this? dealing with same issue since long, not finding any solution.

Comment: @Vicky unfortunately no, I just switched back to node v14.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb". Try installing `"@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "3.165.0"`. This version of "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb" does not use the nullish coalescing operator "??". Therefore, it does not give you this error. I'm surprised more people are not having this problem.